# SWI Prolog: difference lists - fifo

Tags: list, prolog, queue, fifo

I am learning Prolog and difference lists are super new to me and looks like from hell, especially that I am definitely poor simple-minded C++ guy :)
I have problem with my task:

> addall(-E, +G, +S, -R) adds all results of
>   substitutions for the variable E which satisfy
>   the goal G (in which the variable E occurs) to
>   a collection S and returns a new collection R
>   (this predicate resembles the standard predicates findall=3 and findall=4).

I have implemented this with LIFO collection with no problem but something is wrong with FIFO, consider following usage:

```
lifo_empty(L), lifo_addall(X,number(odd,X), L, W).
```

is ok, collection W is [8,6,4,2,0] but:

```
fifo_empty(Q), fifo_addall(X, podstaw(c,X), Q, W).
```

gives me `W = [9, 7, 5, 3|[1|_G3761]-_G3761]`. What I want is `[9,7,5,3,1|_G3761]-_G3761`. I have no idea what is wrong, especially that:

```
?- fifo_empty(Q), fifo_put(a,Q,W), fifo_put(b,W,C).
C = [a, b|_G3922]-_G3922.
```

works just fine. My code:

```
fifo_empty(X-X).
todiff(X, [X|Xs]-Xs).
fifo_put(E, X-[E|Xs], X-Xs).
fifo_get([E|X]-Xs, X-Xs, E).

fifo_append([],S,S).
fifo_append([H|T],S,W) :- fifo_put(H,S,NS), lifo_append(T,NS,W).

fifo_addall(E, Goal, S, R) :- findall(E,Goal, W), fifo_append(W,S,R).
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be happening because you're calling `lifo_append/3` as the last goal in the line:

```
fifo_append([H|T],S,W) :- fifo_put(H,S,NS), lifo_append(T,NS,W).
```

...instead of `fifo_append/3`? Try changing that last subgoal call to `fifo_append/3`. Testing your code with this change with the following facts:

```
person(joe).
person(mary).
```

Gives:

```
?- fifo_empty(Q), fifo_addall(X, person(X), Q, W).
Q = [joe, mary|_G677]-[joe, mary|_G677],
W = [joe, mary|_G677]-_G677.
```

...where `W` binds to the pattern you described you were after.

Comment: Thanks for reply. My problem is that I **have to** do this that way, as it is my homework: implement FIFO using difference lists and make predicat addall(E, Goal, S, R) based on interface provided by FIFO (fifo_add).

Comment: Hmm -- probably would have been good to have made that clear at the outset. Plus, when asking a homework question, it should be tagged as such. I'll have a go at helping you with your code and make an edit to my post if I can figure it out :-)